# How to use CurrentVersion\Run in Windows8

Tags: .net, windows-8

In my application presently when the user selects "Start program automatically" in my options, I add an entry to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

With my program details, now when the user logs onto the system my program starts up.

When I try to do this in Windows8 Consumer Preview upon rebooting nothing happens.

Is there something that I am missing?

Additional Info:
VB6 apps show (once you exit from the start page)
Notepad Shows (once you exit)
.NET apps do not (once you exit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Microsoft Answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_programs/add-an-item-to-the-startup-folder/1b9fd1ee-7bfc-4b53-a561-765f9ab92806?tab=MoreHelp) you should be able to do just that. Try out the Shell:Common approach and see what it does.

I'd also try putting a Microsoft application, like notepad.exe, in place of your app, just to see if it works for something simple like that, or if there is something else going on.

Comment: Have you had a look at your [fusion logs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.71).aspx) to see if the .NET ones are even attempting to start?

Comment: Not even starting. If I run manually it's all fine, but they do not automatically start. I can then look at the fusionlogs and they look fine, but Nothing automatic.

Comment: Do you have any other .NET apps - like Reflector - that you can test with?